# Parent div 100% content of its value, and child div 100% width of its content

Tags: css

Here is my full HTML:

```
<li class="right-menu top-menu">
     <a href="#">Filiale: 950</a>
     <ul class="sub_menu logout-menu">
          <li class="change-filiale menu" value="950"><a href="#">Wähle Filiale:950</a></li>
          <li class="change-filiale menu" value="951"><a href="#">Wähle Filiale:951</a></li>
          <li class="change-filiale menu" value="952"><a href="#">Wähle Filiale:952</a></li>        
     </ul>
</li>
```

I want to have the:

```
<li class="right-menu top-menu">
    <a href="#">Filiale: 950</a>
</li>
```

100 % width of its content and

```
<ul class="sub_menu logout-menu">
    <li class="change-filiale menu" value="950"><a href="#">Wähle Filiale:950</a></li>
    <li class="change-filiale menu" value="951"><a href="#">Wähle Filiale:951</a></li>
    <li class="change-filiale menu" value="952"><a href="#">Wähle Filiale:952</a></li>
</ul>
```

this also 100% of its content. Actually the width of both is the same as the one of the biggest.

Both are relative position and cannot change this, because then the menu is broken. `display: inline-block` is set.

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
.right-menu.top-menu > a {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Also, if your anchor tags are inline-block, you can set width to 100%.

Comment: habe ich schon :/